# Android Bitmap remains unchanged after native C call

Tags: java, android, c, image-processing, java-native-interface

It's the first time I'm using native calls in Android and I'm having trouble getting the result of my image processing function. I've followed the NDK bitmap-plasma example but the bitmap I get is the same as the one I send to the C code.

in Java I have:

```
public class ImageProcessing {

    private static native void processImage(Bitmap  bitmap);

    private static Bitmap imgBitmap;

    public static Bitmap imgPrc_loadAndProcess(Uri img_uri, Context context){
        imgBitmap = null;
        try{
            imgBitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromContentUri(context.getContentResolver(), img_uri);
            processImage(imgBitmap);
            return imgBitmap;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.console().printf(e.toString());

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

in C:

```
extern JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_----_----_----_ImageProcessing_processImage(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj, jobject bitmap)
{
    AndroidBitmapInfo  info;
    void*              pixels;
    int                ret;

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        return ;
    }

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
    }

    ***ImageProcessing stuff that modifies values in *pixels* variable***


    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);

    return ;
}
```

I checked that the C code does indeed change the pixels variable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `, jobject bitmap` You can change that variable but it is a copy of the bitmap of the caller. You have some options though. `, jobject *bitmap`. If that is not possible let your function return the bitmap so you can call it like `imgBitmap=processImage(imgBitmap);`.

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to find an issue in my code that saved the modified values in the pixels variable. Once fixed, **the code in my question does indeed work for getting the changes back in Java**. Hope this helps someone else :)